# How can I interrupt a Jsoup get thread before the timeout?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, jsoup

I have this problem:
I am getting some data in an android asynctask from multiple urls using `Jsoup.connect(url).get()` and then showing it in an Activity. The problem is that sometimes i need to interrupt the threads and free the processor before getting the jsoup result or catching a timeout exception.

The important part of the code code looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            int cpuCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

            BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
            ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    cpuCount,
                    cpuCount,
                    30,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    queue);

            final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(urls.length);

            for (final String url : urls) {
                threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String html = null;
                        try {
                            html = Jsoup.connect(url).get().outerHtml();
                        } catch (Exception ignored) {
                        }

                        if (html != null) {
                            publishProgress(videoStream);
                        }
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    }
                });
            }
        countDownLatch.await();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... result) {
        updateUiStuff(result[0]);
    }
```

The reason i am using a Thread pool executor is that it does the connections in multiple threads in parallel, instead of waiting for one result and the opening a second connection and so on.

I tried doing `cancel(true);` OR `threadPoolExecutor.shutDown();` and `threadPoolExecutor.shutDownNow();` on a button, which was set in onPreExecute but it did not stop the `Runnable`s. Even when i close the activity, the `Runnable`s continue to run until they timeout and until then i can not do anything on the network because the jsoup connections are still running. Please point me in the right direction. Many thanks and i apologize if this is a really stupid question but i could not find a similar one here.

In short: I need to stop the threads when the AsyncTask cancels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` is a general purpose executor that needs some experience to configure. It's a gateway for those experienced programmers whose needs are *not* satisfied (after enough testing) by the executors returned by other factory methods in the `Executors` class. The Javadoc for one of the constructors of this class even documents it:

> It may be more convenient to use one of the `{@link Executors}` factory
>     methods instead of this general purpose constructor.

Are you convinced that you still want to use `ThreadPoolExector`? Note that you can always provide to the methods of the `Executors` the `ThreadFactory` that creates the actual threads that run your async tasks. You do not have to go to `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

In your call above, you make every thread wait 30 seconds (*keepAliveTime*) which makes it wait idly before termination. Are you sure you want that?

You also use just `Runnable` instances as your tasks. Had you considered using `Callable` instances instead, you could have used `submit` method which returns a `Future` which can be canceled. This also facilitates the use of `invokeAll()` method that lets you pass in a collection of `Callable`s and query/cancel the returned `Future`s. You said above that you did `cancel(true)`, but note that that method is only available on a `Future`.

A reliable way to shut down an executor or executor service is:

- Shut it down to attempt orderly shutdown using the `shutdown()` method.
- Await its termination.
- Only if needed, shut it down *now* using the `shutdownNow()` method and if you did, handle the returned list of `Runnable`s properly.
- Handle the exceptions well (this needs to be emphasized). I am sure that `Jsoup.connect` throws various different exceptions and you should handle them correctly. In you case, sadly, you even name the exception variable `ignored`! Please don't believe everything you read on the Internet ;).

After you have gotten some experience with `ExecutorService` this way, you can move on to `CompletionService` which provides `Future`s *as the async tasks complete*. This exploits parallelism rather better especially if the tasks consist of variable IO-bound activity.